# On the spectrum of a compact pertubation of a skew-adjoint operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-functors, fredholm-operators

Let $A\colon \text{dom}(A)\subset H \to H$ ($H$ is a Hilbert space) be a skew-adjoint (i.e. $A^{*}=-A$), closed and densely defined operator. Then the essential spectrum is the set of spectral values $\lambda$ for which $\lambda-A$ is not Fredholm of index zero.
For skew-adjoint operators the spectrum is a subset of the imaginary axis and hence the essential spectrum is a subset of the imaginary axis.
$\textbf{Question}$:
If we consider $\tilde{A}=A+C$ where $C$ is a compact operator,
why is the remainder of the spectrum of $\tilde{A}$ discrete and only consisting of countably many eigenvalues of finite algebraic multiplicity?

Comment: I'm having difficulties to understand the context of the question: how do you know that the statement is true if you don't know a proof or a reference?

Comment: @JochenGlueck  I came across this when I was reading https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.03116.pdf ( on page 9 in the middle part)

Comment: You are perhaps referring to the fact that a compact perturbation doesn't change the essential spectrum. This is known as Weyl's theorem (search for it perhaps).

Comment: @ChristianRemling But also the fact that the remainder of the spectrum is countable with finite algebraic multiplicity. Is there any kind of spectral theorem for Fredholm operators? A itself is not compact which is why I don't think this follows exactly from the spectral theorem for compact operators.